# What transistor should I use (I need to control 12v 5a)?

Tags: transistors, pwm

I am searching for a transistor but I don't know which one I should take and the datasheets are confusing because I'm quite a noob. It needs to be able to control 12v 5a with the circuit from [this website](http://afrotechmods.com/groovy/PWM_tutorial/PWM_tutorial.htm). As you can see on the website it is a PWM circuit.

Please help me...

Comment: Is the 5A because it's for a DC motor? Most likely you are looking at the stall current; in which case you won't hit even close to that amperage under normal operation. Also, if you go to Digikey and search for FETs, you could sort the products to get the components that can handle loads that you are looking for.

Comment: No the 5A is for a LED strip

Comment: I'd personally try 2N3904 first, since it has maximum Collector Emitter Voltage = 40V, at least according to the [datasheet](http://www.futurlec.com/Transistors/2N3904.shtml). Collector current's max is 200mA though, so consider adding couple current-limiting resistors

Comment: @copper.hat As one of the 'old folks' on here I take exception to that comment. Which generation of engineers do you think invented a lot of what you use today?

Comment: @JImDearden: No offence intended. The comment referred to my own age. This may reflect a more analog background, but most designers I knew used transistor to mean BJT and *MOS/FET to refer to non-BJT. My point was to let the OP know why asking about transistors may garner a BJT reply, nothing else intended.

Comment: Very minor point on terminology: For some folks the word 'transistor' may mean something more restrictive (a BJT) than you intended. For PWM stuff of the nature you are dealing with a MOSFET is likely a better choice.

Comment: @copper.hat Accepted. We all stand on the shoulders of those who came before.

Comment: @JImDearden: I stand on the toes of those who came before...

Comment: @copper.hat lol - then placed foot in mouth. Been there, done that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My "go-to" part for low-voltage, medium current DC switching is the IRF3708.  30V, 62A continuous, 0.012 Ohms Rds on.  Drive the gate with a 47 Ohm resistor mounted as close to the gate as possible.